# How to solve with Lambert $W$

Tags: logarithms, lambert-w

I was reading on product log and came upon a [website](https://luckytoilet.wordpress.com/tag/product-log/) which discusses how to solve equations in the form of $we^w=k$.

Given I have the equation:

### $$5+a-6e^{\frac a2}=0$$

How do I solve for $a$ using the Lambert $W$ function?
The website contains some tips:

> So the pattern is to manipulate the equation into $ze^z=k$ where $k$ does not contain the variable. From there, $W(k) = z$, and we can solve it because the variable is in $z$

I can rewrite the equation above into something below, such that the RHS does not contain $a$:

### $$a-6e^{\frac a2}=-5$$

However, I am stuck in transforming the LHS into the form $ze^z$. [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Reduce%5B5+%2B+a+-+6E%5E(a%2F2)+%3D%3D+0,+a%5D) tells me that the answer should be:
$$a=-2W_n\Big(-\frac{3}{e^{\frac52}}\Big)-5 \ \ \mathbb{for} \ n \in \ \mathbb{Z}$$

Additionally, what is the significance of $n$ in $W_n$? How is it used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $-2x = 5+a$ which gives
$$
-2x=6e^{\frac {-5-2x}{2}} = 6e^{\frac {-5}{2}}e^{-x}
$$
or
$$
xe^{x}= -3e^{\frac {-5}{2}}
$$
which is solved by 
$$x=W\Big(-\frac{3}{e^{\frac52}}\Big)$$
and retransformed into 
$$a=-5 - 2W\Big(-\frac{3}{e^{\frac52}}\Big)$$

The $n$ in $W_n$ indices the branch of $W$, i.e. there are several solutions. An illustration is [here (from Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Lambert_W_Range.pdf)

Comment: That should be $a=\color{red}{-5}-2W(-\frac 3{e^{\frac52}})$, but very clever nonetheless!

Comment: @JohnGlenn changed, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**General Method**

For the sake of curious, and for further applications.

Consider an equation of the form

$$p^x = ax + b$$

Through the substitution $x = -t - \frac{b}{a}$ you can rewrite it as

$$ta^t = z$$

Of course with and if $p \neq 0$, $p > 0$ and $a\neq 0$.

That being said, and you have directly the solution in terms of Lambert function:

$$t = \frac{W(z\ln(a))}{\ln(a)}$$

**Other cases**

$$x^x = t ~~~~~~~~~~~ \text{has solution} ~~~~~~~ x = \frac{t}{W(t)}$$

**Without Substitution**

$$p^x = ax + b ~~~~~~~~~~~ \text{has solution} ~~~~~~~ x = \frac{W\left(-\frac{\ln(p)}{a}p^{-b/a}\right)}{\ln(p)} - \frac{b}{a}$$

**More on W Function**

- $$W(x) \approx \ln(x) - \ln(\ln(x)) + o(1)$$
- $$W(x) = \sum_{k = 1}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k!}x^k$$

Comment: Notice that you can simply turn your equation into one of the above written form by using $a\to 2x$.

Answer (score 0):

$$5+a-6e^{a/2}=0$$
Let $x=-\frac{5+a}{2} \quad\to\quad a=-2x-5$
$$-2x=6e^{-x-5/2}$$
$$-2xe^{5/2}=6e^{-x}$$
$$xe^x=-3e^{-5/2}= -\frac{3}{e^{5/2}}$$
From the definition of the Lambert's W function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function :
$$x=W\left(-\frac{3}{e^{5/2}}\right)$$
This function is multi valuated. Formally the two real branches are named $W_0$ and $W_{-1}$. See the above referenced paper.
$$a=-2W_n\left(-\frac{3}{e^{5/2}}\right)-5$$ 
$n=0$  and $n=-1$

As a consequence, on the real domain they are two roots :
$$a\simeq -4.30168 \quad \text{and}\quad a\simeq -0.637368$$
The above values are computed thanks to numerical calculus. You can use the Lambert's W function implemented in math softwares, or directly thanks to iterative method of numerical calculus such as Newton-Raphson.